# JavaScript: // SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

I'm getting this syntax error:

`SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

I tested by removing and adding brackets but can't find the solution if anyone got any tips or a fix please comment.

Code:

https://hastebin.com/onebokigit.js

Edited: Forgot to add the error

```
"} else {"
 ^
```

Comment: We need more information about your code, but this error usually is related to have an invalid JSON object handled as JSON or missing some curve brackets.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  It's likely we can't answer this question as it stands - the cause of the error could be mismatched parentheses way above.   Also, you have two `} else {` in the code you shared and we can't tell which one your error message is pointing at.     The best way to solve this is to use an editor that understands javascript syntax, and shows you the matching parentheses.    This question is likely to be closed because it is not an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).   By the time you cut your code down to be an MCVE you will likely have found the problem.

Comment: Sorry about that its the last one

Comment: You said that it's the last else, but the code you posted doesn't include the opening brace leading up to that else.   I didn't find any mismatched braces in the section you pasted.

Answer (score -1):

It seems an extra '}' curly braces after else block.

if possible please share complete method, may be overlooked by you or anything you missed out, extra eyes always works:)

Comment: @ImChicken can you please accept my answer, if the issue is because of extra curly braces.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly where the extra bracket is I updated the code showing the full code.

Comment: ok,now looks like curly brackets are fine, have you tried to use `format()` method without any argument.